# Maximum power transfer problem. Find the resistance

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, current, resistors, homework

I'm new here and I would like to know if anyone here can help with this question below.

Which resistor must be connected to the circuit of the following image to transfer to it the maximum power?

[image: image of question]

My attempt:

[image: my attempt]

Comment: Hint: Find the Thevenin equivalent resistance.

Comment: Another hint - Maximum power transfer occurs when the load impedance equals the source impedance.    You could determine that analytically, or maybe by trying a bunch of numbers (in excel or such), or you can just remember that general rule (which your professor apparently hasn't yet shared with you....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is super simple; It's 12kOhm.

Why?

The 18kOhm resistor is in parallel with a voltage source, ie. it has NO influence on anything, throw it away..

The 6kOhm resistor is in series with a current source ie. it has NO influence on anything, throw it away..

What are you left with?

And so what is the output impedance of your circuit???

To get maximum power transfer you just need the load to have the same value as the output impedance of the circuit.

This should be easy enough for you to solve now. (He did solve it)

Comment: so 12kohms. and then the V of the circuit is 8V and not 30V as I thought...

Comment: I didn't see anything about a voltage in your question so I didn't consider it, but you are correct that the load needs to be 12kOhm. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Ognum and BTW no, the voltage "V" is not 8V.

Comment: V = Isc * Req = 5mA * 12kohm = 60V

Comment: What makes you think that "Isc" is 5mA? is certainly isn't. Assuming that you had 60V at the output, what would the current "backwards" through the 12kOhm resistor be? (60V-8V)/12kOhm = 52V/12kOhm = 4.333mA ... So you claim that 5mA is flowing to the load? and you claim that the voltage at the output is 60V ie. 4.33mA flows from the output through the 12kOhm resistor into the 8V source, where are those 4.333mA coming from? out of thin air?

Comment: thanks, man! Now I think I made everything ok and it turns out that Isc is 17/3 mA. (its one of the options solution in my problem so i think its ok)

Comment: Sorry dude but 17/3mA is not correct either.

Comment: This really is a super basic problem in electronics. If you want to become an electronics professional I can promis you that you will have to be able to solve this in your head in under a minute, like I'm doing, so you might as well lean it sooner rather than later.. A hint is use the superposition principle.

Comment: I'll get there. I'm new at this. Began to study these stuff two weeks ago. I did a plus instead of a minus so its 13/3mA

Comment: @Ognum if you keep trying I'm sure you'll get through the entire list of options ;) ;) ;). No it is not 13/3mA either.. Look we were all new at this at one point and when I was just two weeks into it I had difficulties with this too, I'm just saying that you need to pay attention to this and study it hard because it is basic and essential to everything in electronics. In other words you should not be so concerned with getting the correct multiple-choice answer you should be concerned with getting the understanding down, screw what results you get at a test, it's understanding that matters.

Comment: Thanks for the words! I really appreciate this. I'll study this problem better and perhaps get the right answer...

Comment: If I could interject, I would suggest that on occasions like this it can be useful to use a circuit simulator to generate the values for you so you can check AFTER you've done the calculations. This would save you from running around in circles and asking Vinzent for every value, though I'm sure they don't mind. LTSpice or Multisim would be a good option if you're at University.

Answer (score 0):

> First, I will present a method that uses [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) to solve this problem because you already have a good answer by [@Vinzent](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/173292/vinzent). When I was studying this stuff I used the method all the time (without using Mathematica of course).

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbIwjy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_\text{i}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_\text{k}+\text{I}_2\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{i}=\text{I}_1+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\text{I}_\text{k}+\text{I}_3
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_\text{k}=\frac{\text{V}_2-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_4}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

Now, we can set-up a Mathematica-code to solve for all the voltages and currents:

```
In[1]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{Ii == I1 + I2, I4 == Ik + I2, Ii == I1 + I3, I4 == Ik + I3, 
   I1 == Vi/R1, I2 == (Vi - V1)/R2, Ik == (V2 - V1)/R3, 
   I4 == V1/R4}, {Ii, I1, I2, I3, I4, V1, V2}]]

Out[1]={{Ii -> Vi/R1 + (-Ik R4 + Vi)/(R2 + R4), I1 -> Vi/R1, 
  I2 -> (-Ik R4 + Vi)/(R2 + R4), I3 -> (-Ik R4 + Vi)/(R2 + R4), 
  I4 -> (Ik R2 + Vi)/(R2 + R4), V1 -> (R4 (Ik R2 + Vi))/(R2 + R4), 
  V2 -> (Ik R2 R3 + Ik (R2 + R3) R4 + R4 Vi)/(R2 + R4)}}
```

Now, we can find:

$$\text{P}_{\text{R}_4}=\text{V}_{\text{R}_4}\cdot\text{I}_{\text{R}_4}=\text{V}_1\cdot\text{I}_4=\text{R}_4\cdot\left(\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{I}_\text{k}\text{R}_2}{\text{R}_2+\text{R}_4}\right)^2\tag3$$

So, we want to find \$\frac{\partial\text{P}_{\text{R}_4}}{\partial\text{R}_4}=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{R}_4=\dots\$. In order to solve it, I used the following Mathematica-code:

```
In[3]:=FullSimplify[
 Solve[{D[(R4 (Ik R2 + Vi))/(R2 + R4)*(Ik R2 + Vi)/(R2 + R4), R4] == 
    0, R4 > 0 && Ik > 0 && Vi < 0 && R2 > 0}, R4]]

Out[3]={{R4 -> ConditionalExpression[R2, Vi < 0 && R2 > 0 && Ik > 0]}}
```

> Using your values we get:
>
> $$\text{R}_4=\text{R}_2=12\space\text{k}\Omega\tag6$$